# How do I include a calculation function in a menu item in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a menu item and want to run a function within that menu which will run a simple calculation based on a entry. When I run the code in my terminal, I can see my window and the menu item with the entry widget. But, I don't see anything and result from my function. I don't get an error from the terminal. Below is my code. Where did I mess in my code?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title(" My calculator")
root.geometry("400x400")

# Defining  calculator 1 function 
def calculator_1():
    
    # creating an entry 
    frame1.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
    e1 =Entry(frame1)
    e1.pack(pady=5)

    # Defining the formula function
    
    def formula():
        res = (int(e1.get()) +  1)  
        myText.set(res)

    # creating a calculate button
        my_button = Button(frame1, text="Click to calculate", command=formula)
        my_button.pack(pady=5)

        myText=StringVar()
        result=Label(frame1, text=" your results is  ", textvariable =myText)
        result.pack(pady=5)

        label_result =Label(frame1, text= "Your result is")
        label_result.pack(pady=5)

# Define Main menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

#create menu items
math_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="MathCards",menu=math_menu)
math_menu.add_command(label="Calculator 1",command=calculator_1)
math_menu.add_separator()
math_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

# Creating a frame
frame1 = Frame(root, width =400, height=400)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try unindenting everything between the `my_button = Button(...)` and `label_result.pack(...)`. So it should be in `calculator_1` but not in `formula`

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working perfectly

Comment: That is why people don't recommend using nested functions. But nice to hear that your problem is solved